# TYPO3 9.5: Replace RealURL-code with Advanced Routing Configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

How do I get this code from RealURL into the TYPO3 9.5 'Advanced Routing Configuration'?

With 'aspects' type 'PersistedAliasMapper', you can only map to the UID.
But I want to map to another field!
In my case over the '**event_id**' field.

```
array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_extension_search[eventid]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_extension_domain_model_event',
                        'id_field' => 'event_id',
                        'alias_field' => 'title_alias',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 0,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add a `slug` field. With this the editor can handle the url segment of every record.
Here are the needed changes:

SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tx_extension_domain_model_event (
  slug varchar(1024) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

TCA of `tx_extension_domain_model_event`

```php
        'slug' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.slug',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'slug',
                'size' => 50,
                'generatorOptions' => [
                    'fields' => ['title'],
                    'replacements' => [
                        '/' => '-'
                    ],
                ],
                'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
                'default' => ''
            ]
        ],
```

The configuration in your `config.yaml`, with e.g. `showAction` to show the details of an event:

```yml
routeEnhancers:
  YourPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: ExtensionKey
    plugin: Search
    limitToPages: [Put your detailPagePid here]
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/event/{event}', _controller: 'Event::show', _arguments: {'event': 'event'}}
    defaultController: 'Event::show'
    aspects:
      event:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_extension_domain_model_event'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
```